# set an argument to remove NAs in a function

Tags: r, function, na

I am trying to complete a function. Hopefully, sometime in the future, I may share it with other users. In this function, I would like to have an argument so that users will have an option either excluding all missing values in all analyses or  as it is based on data available for different components. I wonder if there is a standard way to do this or a `r` rule for this.

To show my point:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, NA, 7),
           y = c(2, NA, 4, 5, 6, 7, NA))

myfun <- function(data, na.omit = FALSE, ...) {
  if (na.omit == TRUE) {
    data <- na.omit(data)
  }  
  # computing a lot of things 
  print(data)
}

myfun(data = mydata, na.omit = F)  

myfun(data = mydata, na.omit = T)
```

Although it works fine now, I am still a little worried about this because `na.omit` is an existing `r` function. Should I change this argument into something like `na_omit` or `complete_set`?

Comment: Yes it's better to name it something not already defined. Also, You don't need to do `if (na.omit == TRUE)`, you can just do `if (na.omit)`. If it is true, it will evaluate it...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions which are helpful! I will change my code accordingly.

Comment: Best to use TRUE and FALSE rather than T and F as T and F can be variables whereas TRUE and FALSE cannot.

Comment: Thank you for the  advice. I will change that and practice it in the future.